# Reducer not called after action is dispatched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get started on **react/redux** using the boilerplate code from http://reactboilerplate.com and it worked great until now.

I want to update my state from a container, and I'm dispatching a call like this:

```
// This is the method that should tigger the action
updateMoneyValue(newValue);

...

// Here I hope I set up everything correctly...
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    updateMoneyValue: newMoneyValue =>
      dispatch(updateMoneyValue(newMoneyValue)),
  };
}
const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'counterPage', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'counterPage', saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(CounterPage);
```

I thought that the `dispatch(updateMoneyValue(newMoneyValue))` should actually dispatch the action and have it hit the reducer. But actually what happens is that when I perform the call in the first line, my action is triggered:

```
export function updateMoneyValue(moneyValue) {
  console.log('Action has fired.');
  return {
    type: UPDATE_MONEY_VALUE,
    moneyValue,
  };
}
```

But the reducer never runs:

```
function counterPageReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_MONEY_VALUE:
      console.log('Reducer was called.');
      state.set('moneyValue', action.moneyValue);
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I tried to find the solution, but I'm really stuck on this one and would appreciate any help!

Best regards,
Ayaka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling `updateMoneyValue(newValue)`, you're not dispatching the action, you're calling the action creator directly.

To go through Redux, you need to call `this.props.updateMoneyValue(newValue)`

Answer (score 0):

change:

`state.set('moneyValue', action.moneyValue);`

to:

`state = state.set('moneyValue', action.moneyValue);`

edit: that way, you "set the new state", without the `state =` you are changing the state but not using the changed state to later return it

Answer (score 0):

When you map the state or dispatch your method become available in the props.

```
// This is the method that should tigger the action
this.props.updateMoneyValue(newValue);
```